# Не получается сделать анимацию смерти в Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d, анимация

Я делаю 2d шутер с зомби и хочу сделать анимацию смерти, но не понимаю как. Когда у главного героя здоровье опускается до 0, то у меня он просто удаляется со сцены. Я хочу сделать чтобы была анимация смерти, прежде чем удалиться игрок.

Вот код

```
public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private int _health;

    private int _currentHealth;

    private void Start()
    {
        _currentHealth = _health;
    }

    public void TakeDamage(int damage)
    {
        _currentHealth -= damage;

        if (_currentHealth <= 0)
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

Я был на многих сайтов, где предлагается использовать корутину или создать 2го игрока где будет включатся его текстурка с анимацией смерти. Буду рад если посоветуете что-то еще.

Comment: Что-то не видно, где вы хотя-бы пытаетесь использовать анимацию.

Comment: Анимацию все настроил, даже логику в Animator сделал. Я просто хочу узнать как правильно ее использовать.

Comment: Как правильно  использовать анимацию - это не то что вы спросили в своём вопросе.

Answer (score -2):

```
private int _currentHealth;
// время, которое нужно выждать до удаления объекта.
private static float _deathDelay = 5.0f;

private void Start()
{
    _currentHealth = _health;
}

public void TakeDamage(int damage)
{
    _currentHealth -= damage;   

    if (_currentHealth <= 0)
    {
        //сначала проигрывай анимацию, а затем 
        StartCoroutine(DestroyDelay(_deathDelay));
    }
}

private IEnumerator DestroyDelay(float time)
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(time);
    Destroy(gameObject);
    
}
```

Comment: ну или вместо coroutine - Destroy(gameObject, _deathDelay);

Comment: Щас бы в 2к23 при смерти запускать коронтину чтобы удалить игрока. Пишется специльный обработчик для Update, который создает события через N секунд. В наших проектах миллисекунд. В этом обработчике так же есть функция выполнить по истечению анимации событие. Событие я подразумеваю на ссылку метода. Где уже удаляется объект. Это первое, второе - это отнимать через Clamp нужно жизни. И нет проверки на меньше 0. Знаете что дает минус на минус? Плюс! Я кину урон в аргумент -15. И в итоге добавлю жизней врагу

Comment: @Alexey напишите свой правильный ответ. Про `Clamp` несогласен. Если надо запретить отрицательное значение, то следует бросать исключение, чтобы разработчик, использующий метод, сразу понял, что-то пошло не по плану, а не выискивал баг через странное поведение. "В любой непонятной ситуации бросай исключение", так отлаживать код будет в разы легче.